# JPA Sequence Generated Value Not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sequence

I need to use an existing sequence of the db to generate the id of this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="sistema", name="clientes_consultas")
public class Consulta implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(schema = "sistema",  sequenceName = "clientes_consultas_id_seq", 
    name = "seq_c", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_c")
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This is my sequence, and its stored on a schema that is not the postgres default 'public', its called 'sistema':

### [image]

Unfortunately, theres an stacktrace saying that the sequence dont exists :(

Any clue?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please? It might give us more of a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence owner is "postgres". Maybe you defined different user than postgres in your connection.